# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.removeViewAt(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

Ошибка:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.removeViewAt(int)' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at com.arvicapps.geomitric_wallpapers.FavoriteFullImageActivity$5.onFavoriteChanged(FavoriteFullImageActivity.java:533)
        at com.github.ivbaranov.mfb.MaterialFavoriteButton.updateFavoriteButton(MaterialFavoriteButton.java:324)
        at com.github.ivbaranov.mfb.MaterialFavoriteButton.setFavorite(MaterialFavoriteButton.java:257)
        at com.github.ivbaranov.mfb.MaterialFavoriteButton.toggleFavorite(MaterialFavoriteButton.java:292)
W/System.err:     at com.github.ivbaranov.mfb.MaterialFavoriteButton$1.onClick(MaterialFavoriteButton.java:152)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6659)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6631)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:790)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26187)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
```

Вот части кода из FavouriteFullImageActivity.java: @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite_full_image); getSupportActionBar().hide(); RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.FavoriteCategoryView); }

Вот части кода из FavouriteFullImageActivity.java:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite_full_image); getSupportActionBar().hide(); RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.FavoriteCategoryView); 
}
```

```
try {
 recyclerView.removeViewAt(position); recyclerView.notifyAll(); 
myDbHelper.closeDb(); 
myDbHelper.close(); 
myDbHelper.notifyAll(); 
} catch (NullPointerException nullPointerException) { nullPointerException.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Как решить?

Comment: ну для начала показать код который эту ошибку выводит, экстрасенсов среди нас нет

Comment: Вот части кода из FavouriteFullImageActivity.java: @Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite_full_image);

getSupportActionBar().hide();

RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.FavoriteCategoryView); }

Comment: try {

recyclerView.removeViewAt(position);

recyclerView.notifyAll();

myDbHelper.closeDb();

myDbHelper.close();

myDbHelper.notifyAll();

} catch (NullPointerException nullPointerException) {

nullPointerException.printStackTrace();

}

Comment: `recyclerView.removeViewAt(position);` здесь  `recyclerView` равен `null`. Исправьте это и код будет работать

Comment: @ArchDemon Я инициализировал переменную recyclerView в onCreate.  И выдаёт тоже самую ошибку.